# Android Studio: errors when adding 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1' to Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

(Android Studio 2.3.3) This is my Gradle Build file. I am finding it very frustrating as I have only added the last 'support:appcompat' line and I get a load of errors:

C:\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v24\values-v24.xml
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
Error:(4) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.
.
.
Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
      compileSdkVersion 'Google Inc.:Google APIs:23'
      buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

      useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

      defaultConfig {
          applicationId "ab.cdefghij.xyz"
          minSdkVersion 14
          targetSdkVersion 19
      }

      buildTypes {
          debug {
              debuggable true
          }
          release {
              minifyEnabled false
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
          }
      }
  }

  dependencies {
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
      compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
      compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
  }
```

I have a styles.xml containing a CustomActionBarTheme (Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar) so what are all these weird errors? The AppCompat replaces the original Holo one, and what is this values-v24.xml?
I get some unhelpful messages from gradle about finding different build versions, but this whole scenario is one of the most confusing I have ever encountered with Android Studio.

I just need a combination of these numbers, ie 25.0.0, etc, that will allow this whole thing to compile.

Comment: `compileSdkVersion` isn't API 25, so why are you trying to use the support library for version 25?

Comment: I am not sure. I was confused about all the messages Gradle keeps telling me about using the latest versions, etc. I have Google Api 24 so will try switching to that and see what happens.

Comment: I am not sure. I was confused about all the messages Gradle keeps telling me about using the latest versions, etc. I have Google Api 24 so will try switching to that and see what happens. OK I have reset BuildTools to 23.0.03 and it says too low for project, mimimum is 25.0.0. So change and then I get Failed to resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.3 so back to 25.3.1 producing the original errors! I hope you can see why I am totally confused.

Comment: It can't resolve a version until you download it

Comment: And again, using version 24 won't let you compile version  25 libraries

Comment: Gradle console says, in bold, The SDK Build Tools revision (23.0.3) is too low for project. Mimimum required is 25. This is when I am using version 23.

Comment: You're reading that wrong. Minimum required is 25. In other words, you can't use anything lower than 25. You should always use the latest build tools. The support libraries cannot be higher than the compileSdk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151931/discussion-between-archdeacon-and-cricket-007).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have three components here that need to be corrected.

1) Build tools.

This should always be the latest version when working out library issues

2) compileSdk

It does not hurt to make this the latest version, especially if wanting to run on the latest Android devices. Some methods/classes may be deprecated or removed, but in most cases you'll be fine

This is where the error comes from

> values-v24\values-v24.xml Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches

You are not compiling API v24, so your resource files can't be generated, causing

> Cannot resolve symbol 'R'

3) Your dependencies

The support library versions can't be higher than the compileSdk, and they must all match, otherwise, you'll be including code that can't be compiled, as mentioned in the errors

Comment: Many thanks sir. Your helpful suggestions eventually fixed the problem for me.